# Same code on multiple pages

Tags: html

So I have like quite a number of web pages and it's hard to change the code on every page one by on every time. I noticed like Stack Overflow they have the same header for each page so can someone please teach me how to do it?
Thank you

Comment: Lookup scripting (PHP, ASP.Net)

Comment: You need to narrow it down your question. What server language are you using? Ruby, PHP, Java, ... ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a page templating technology like JSP (Java) or ASP (.net) or Jade (nodejs/express), jinja2 (python/flask) etc., to generate html pages with common templates.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are working with plain HTML static files. You would benefit tremendously by learning some server side language so you can dynamically generate web pages with content stored in a repository of your choice (i.e a database).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a scripting language such as PHP and use a function to include other files within the script. Here's an example in PHP:

```
<?php
include "someheader.html";
?>
<p>Some html text here</p>
<?php
include "somefooter.html";
?>
```